Wifi issue: Connection failed (Activation of network connection failed) 22.04

I have a dual boot system. While connecting to WiFi, it stays in the connecting state and then I encountered the error 'Connection failed (Activation of network connection failed)'. I tried some commands like
sudo apt install --reinstall linux-headers-$(uname -r)
and
sudo rebbot
it didn't work on my case so please help me Out.
Can you please help me out?

